# Using elif statement "print function" not working correctly instead printing if statement's "print function" instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random, printing

I am trying to make a selection tool to pick my next anime, I used the random package to select which one would be the next to watch and this works correctly my issue lies in the following I want to add a description to the selected show, for example, if it picks show b I want to know what it's about. The current issue is that the print function in the elif statement arent working and instead it keeps choosing the description of the first one.

```
import random

print("Project Select")
print("")
#for future me
print("Summary Of Project: This Project Has The Goal To Help Select What Anime I Should Watch Next")
print("")
Anime = ["Black Bullet","Princess Connect","Overlord","Date A Live", "Chivalry of a failed knight", "The Detective Is Already Dead",
"Shimoneta", "I'm Quitting Heroing","The Greateast Mage"]

selector = random.choice(Anime)

print(selector)

if("Black Bullet"):
    print("Banana 1")
elif("Princess Connect"):
    print("Watermelon 2")
elif("Overlord"):
    print("Strawberry 3")
elif("Date A Live"):
    print("kiwi 4")
elif("Chivalry Of A Failed Knight"):
    print("apple 5")
elif("The Detective Is Already Dead"):
    print("blueberry 6")
elif("Shimoneta"):
    print("lemon 7")
elif("I'm Quitting Heroing"):
    print("cherry 8")
else:
    print("orange 9")
```

Comment: This is not how the syntax of an if-elif-else statement works. I believe you need to look up some very basic Python syntax first.

Comment: `"Black Bullet"` is a string with non-zero length, and therefore truthy, so the `if` branch will always be taken.  Did you intend to compare to `selector` (i.e. `if selector == "Black Bullet":`)?

Comment: @MilesBudnek I did not intend to do that but thanks for pointing it out it fixed the issue, sorry if this was a stupid post this was the first real-time I use python for non-learning purposes.

Comment: This is one of the possible tutorials on the subject:  https://favtutor.com/blogs/python-switch-case

Comment: Or possibly the OP should investigate structural pattern matching.

Comment: Also, the parens around your expressions in the if/elif are entirely extraneous unless you need to group to overcome operator precedence.

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect the code `if("Black Bullet"):` to do? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `==` operator like so:

```
import random

print("Project Select")
print("")
#for future me
print("Summary Of Project: This Project Has The Goal To Help Select What Anime I Should Watch Next")
print("")
Anime = ["Black Bullet","Princess Connect","Overlord","Date A Live", "Chivalry of a failed knight", "The Detective Is Already Dead",
"Shimoneta", "I'm Quitting Heroing","The Greateast Mage"]

selector = random.choice(Anime)

print(selector)

if selector == "Black Bullet":
    print("Banana 1")
elif selector == "Princess Connect":
    print("Watermelon 2")
elif selector == "Overlord":
    print("Strawberry 3")
elif selector == "Date A Live":
    print("kiwi 4")
elif selector == "Chivalry Of A Failed Knight":
    print("apple 5")
elif selector == "The Detective Is Already Dead":
    print("blueberry 6")
elif selector == "Shimoneta":
    print("lemon 7")
elif selector == "I'm Quitting Heroing":
    print("cherry 8")
else:
    print("orange 9")
```

Here is why your code didn't work:

For the `if` - `elif` statements, you had:

```
if("Black Bullet"):
    print("Banana 1")
elif("Princess Connect"):
    print("Watermelon 2")
elif("Overlord"):
    print("Strawberry 3")
elif("Date A Live"):
    print("kiwi 4")
elif("Chivalry Of A Failed Knight"):
    print("apple 5")
elif("The Detective Is Already Dead"):
    print("blueberry 6")
elif("Shimoneta"):
    print("lemon 7")
elif("I'm Quitting Heroing"):
    print("cherry 8")
else:
    print("orange 9")
```

which was telling Python: *"If the boolean value for `"Black Bullet"` is equal to `True`, then execute `print("Banana 1")`, else, if the boolean value of..."* and so on.

The only way for a string's boolean value to be `False` is when the string is empty, so you get why the code only printed `Banana 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of syntax for Python 3.x (Python3 in short). By the way you have typo "Chivalry of a failed knight" should be "Chivalry Of A Failed Knight"

```
import random

print("Project Select")
print("")
#for future me
print("Summary Of Project: This Project Has The Goal To Help Select What Anime I Should Watch Next")
print("")
Anime = ["Black Bullet", "Princess Connect", "Overlord", "Date A Live", "Chivalry Of A Failed Knight", "The Detective Is Already Dead",
"Shimoneta", "I'm Quitting Heroing", "The Greateast Mage"]

selector = random.choice(Anime)

print(selector)

if selector == "Black Bullet":
    print("Banana 1")
elif selector == "Princess Connect":
    print("Watermelon 2")
elif selector == "Overlord":
    print("Strawberry 3")
elif selector == "Date A Live":
    print("kiwi 4")
elif selector == "Chivalry Of A Failed Knight":
    print("apple 5")
elif selector == "The Detective Is Already Dead":
    print("blueberry 6")
elif selector == "Shimoneta":
    print("lemon 7")
elif selector == "I'm Quitting Heroing":
    print("cherry 8")
elif selector == "The Greateast Mage":
    print("orange 9")
else:
    print("Not Found!")
```

Output:

```
Project Select

Summary Of Project: This Project Has The Goal To Help Select What Anime I Should Watch Next

The Detective Is Already Dead
blueberry 6
```

The if-statement will give a true if the string is not ("") empty. For example:

```
if("helloworld"):
    print("yes")    #yes

if(""):
    print("yes")    #no output
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is that your first `if` statement will ALWAYS evaluate to `True`, and cause the code indented inside that block to run. Non-empty strings evaluate to `True`:

```py
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("hello")
True
```

To fix your problem, you will want to check for the equality of `selector`, which will contain whatever is returned by `random.choice(Anime)`. Here is a simple example:

```py
>>> import random
>>> def foo(lst):
...     rand = random.choice(lst)
...     if rand == 1:
...         print("1 is the element")
...     elif rand == 2:
...         print("2 is the element")
...     elif rand == 3:
...         print("3 is the element")
...
>>> foo([1, 2, 3])
1 is the element
>>> foo([1, 2, 3])
2 is the element
>>> foo([1, 2, 3])
2 is the element
>>> foo([1, 2, 3])
1 is the element
>>> foo([1, 2, 3])
3 is the element
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answers offered, you may wish to use a dictionary to associate names with foods.

```
assoc = {
  'Black Bullet':                  'Banana 1',
  'Princess Connect':              'Watermelon 2',
  'Overlord':                      'Strawberry 3',
  'Date A Live':                   'kiwi 4',
  'Chivalry Of A Failed Knight':   'apple 5',
  'The Detective Is Already Dead': 'blueberry 6',
  'Shimoneta':                     'lemon 7',
  'I\'m Quitting Heroing':         'cherry 8'
}
```

Now you can simply:

```
print(assoc.get(selector, 'Not found!'))
```

Using `assoc.get(selector, 'Not found!')` rather than `assoc[selector]` lets us supply a default value to return if the index is not found in the dictionary, thus replacing the `else` in a if/elif/else statement.

If you need to get all of the names, you can just use:

```
list(assoc.keys())
```